# Написать аннотацию времени компиляции (java)

Tags: java, аннотации

есть метод

```java
mmmm(String str){
String ss="bla" + param +"bla-bla";
}
```

param - это внешнее значение, которое необходимо вставить для данного использования метода
хотелось бы так

```java
@annn(value="param")
mmmm(String str){
тут что-то чтоб в результате в рантайме была готовая строка с param
}
```

надо написать аннотацию и как её применить.

Comment: Если используете спринг (равно как и любой другой фреймворк,  основанный на контейнере), то проблем нет, эта функция из коробки. в противном случае все не так просто

Comment: чистая java, поэтому и нужна помощь общества

Comment: Эту проблему можно решить с помощью АОП - на этапе компиляции умеет отрабатывать AspectJ. Создаете аспект, который тригерится на вашу аннотацию - и с помощью рефлексии делаете что угодно. Другой вопрос - что настроить это довольно трудоёмко.

Comment: тогда что делает аннотация времени компиляции? вроде как может что-то генерить?